# OpenNI 1.5.7.10 x64 Windows 7 & drivers

Tags: c++, windows, kinect, openni

I am porting to windows 7 a OpenNI program that works perfectly on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 on the next machine.

I have installed OpenNI 1.5.7.10 x64 and Visual C++ 2010. The program compiles and links, but when executing, it can not create the User Generator. Gives the following error:

"Can´t create any node of the requested type!"

The code is:

```
nRetVal = g_Context.FindExistingNode(XN_NODE_TYPE_USER, g_UserGenerator);
  if (nRetVal != XN_STATUS_OK)
  {
    nRetVal = g_UserGenerator.Create(g_Context);
    CHECK_RC(nRetVal, "Find user generator");
  }
```

The kinect driver, after having so many problems, has been installed from:
https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect/tree/unstable/Bin

In its 64 bin version. It is working ok, the examples run, but my program is not capable of detecting the Kinect.

Could anyone give a hand, it would be highly appreciated !!!

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you using the same Kinect driver in ubuntu as well? The samples work ok with the Kinect?, it is only the user_node the one that gives you the error? or the others as well? Have you tried the OpenNI/NiUserTracker sample?

Comment: The code in Ubuntu with the same driver works fine. The problem is in Windows, porting the same code.